# Assign awk to variables in php

Tags: php, awk

I have the following code in place. It provides the information needed, however I would like to assign the output to variables.

```
$cmd = "ssh machine 'cat /usr/local/reports/file.dat | awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*' '{print \"<tr><td>\"$2\"</td><td>\"$3\"</td></tr>\"}'";
system($cmd);
```

This correctly runs and produces a table with the 2nd and 3rd columns from the file. However, I would now like to assign the columns to variables for each line read in the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions:

1. Use [`heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to make reader friendly
2. avoid `cat /usr/local/reports/file`, `awk` can read file directly, there is no need of using `cat` command
3. if you want take care of return status use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. 
   [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns all of the output stream as a string. `exec` returns the last line of the output by default, but can provide all output as an array specifed as the second parameter.

**Here is code snippet**

```
<?php

$cmd =<<<EOF
ssh user@host "awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*' '{
               print \"<tr><td>\" $2 \"</td><td>\" $3 \"</td></tr>\" 
           }
           ' /usr/local/reports/file.dat 2>&1"
EOF;

/* 
     execute command in 1st argument, 
     save output in array in 2nd argument  
     store status in 3rd argument
*/
exec($cmd, $out, $return);

if($return==0)
{
    print_r($out);

       /* your case you can just 
          echo implode(PHP_EOL, $out);
       */   
}else{
    /* Failed to execute command 
       do some error handling */ 

    die( 'Failed to execute command : '. $cmd );
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see why a heredoc would improve the readability here. Especially when it appears in an indented block.

Comment: @hek2mgl true, but when you have so many things instead of quotes heredoc looks clean.

Comment: Ok, I don't have to agree with that heredoc thingy but the remaining parts of the answer are good!

Answer (score 2):

[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) always outputs the command output directly. You could use output buffering to capture it, but you should use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead:

```
$result = shell_exec( $cmd );
```